# how to check Valid driver name while testing JDBC connection in java

Tags: java, database, oracle, validation, jdbc

I have added multiple jars(ojdbc6 for oracle and jtds-1.2.jar for sqlserver ) to my classpath.
When I test connection using following code :

```
           Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
          System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
         if(conn==null){
             System.out.println("false");
         }
         else{
             System.out.println("true");
         }
```

Scenario 1:
If I give JDBC_DRIVER as sqlserver URL (net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver)
and DB_URL,USER,PASS for my oracle instance then also it will create connection for me  but logically it is wrong.

Scenario 2:
If I give some other(not oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver ) valid class in ojdbc6.jar and valid DB_URL,USER,PASS then also it will create connection .

But I always want to check valid JDBC_DRIVER which corresponds to the given DB_URL,USER,PASS

I have also tried registerDriver and deregisterDriver API available in driverManager. What are the pros and cons of using it.

Comment: Don't use `Class.forName()`. `DriverManager.getConnection()` will figure out the correct class based on the URL. If no driver is available for the URL given, you will get an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation for - *Scenario 1/Scenario 2***

From [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html)

> Applications **no longer need to explictly load JDBC drivers using Class.forName()**. Existing programs which currently load JDBC drivers using Class.forName() **will continue to work without modification**.

So even you comment out `Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);` you will get the same result as ojdbc6 is in your classpath and in `DriverManager.getConnection(...);` method you are passing oracle database related information.So `DriverManager` always will return the connection instance for oracle daabase only.

**Explanation for- *want to check valid JDBC_DRIVER which corresponds to the given DB_URL,USER,PASS***

For this you can use [getDriver(String url)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getDriver-java.lang.String-) method of **DriverManager** class.

> getDriver(String url)
>
> Attempts to locate a driver that understands the given URL.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works using getDriver method of DriverManager.   One more thing i have tied is  -:                                     Driver currentDriver;
  Connection con=null;currentDriver = (Driver) Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER).newInstance();
   con=currentDriver.connect(dbURL, properties);

Answer (score 0):

To check valid driver name try these lines below.

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(this.dbUrl, this.dbUser, this.dbPassword);
DatabaseMetaData dbMetaData = conn.getMetaData();
this.databaseProperties.add("Driver Name: " + dbMetaData.getDriverName());
```